# Apache URL rewriting do not work correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have an issue with URL-rewriting in `.htaccess`. Here is an extract of the file:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(content\.php\?page=)(.+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

I need to rewrite url like `"content.php?page=quality-policy"` to `"quality-policy.php"`.

But I see this:

```
Not Found
The requested URL content.php was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^content\.php$ %1.php [L]
```

Explanation:
  if %{QUERY_STRING} contains page=something then

Rewrite the URL content.php to something.php

%1 is the regex backreference in RewriteCond, not to be confused with $1 that is the 1st backreference in the matched RewriteRule regex. The flag [L] imposes that this is the last rule to be executed, ignoring all rules that follow if any.